# Rackmount server is beeping

Tags: hardware

I walked in today to hear that a Cisco rackmount server was beeping in the server room. It is beeping constantly on and off (one second on, one second off) continuously.

I am just an intern working here for the summer and both of my supervisors aren't here today and right now I am just concerned with silencing the beeping because it's driving the front office of the company crazy. I asked one of our higher ups and he said just to leave it alone for now (and not restart it) because he doesn't want anything to stop working.

The server itself is up and running and I tried looking through the event logs to find anything that would cause it and I see nothing. There are no hard disk errors and raid is working properly (as far as I can tell). Can someone please at least tell me how I can silence the beeping?

Comment: It's really crazy that being an intern you have no supervisor available on any given day. I think that you should give a heads up to the management about this situation.

Have you tried reading the manuals for the equipment?

Are you cleared to silence an alarm? If not you may get into some troubles. Ask for a waiver if not explicitly allowed to do so.

Comment: If there's a Supermicro server nearby or any server with an LSI RAID controller, the beep could be a power supply failure or a failed disk in RAID.

Comment: lsof | grep pcm might yield some info?

Comment: Also see: https://serverfault.com/questions/56143/server-is-beeping?rq=1 Many suggestions there for troubleshooting.

Comment: This really is a sticky situation. One supervisor is on vacation for the week, the other just took off for today leaving me with users wanting to chew my head off because I can't turn off this constant beeping. It's a Cisco UCS C220 M3 Server. I am looking through the manual for it right now.

Comment: Is the system status (triangle) led on? If it's beeping I would expect that to be on or flashing if it has detected a fault

Comment: The system status led is in fact blinking.

Comment: To be honest I would probably be wanting to contact the person who is supposedly responsible for this server, or getting your manager involved to contact them. It looks like the server does have a network management interface, but there's no guarantee this was connected/configured, and if it is connected you'll need login details to access it. Either way this isn't something an intern should be solely responsible for sorting out. If this was at my company I'd expect to be called back in to fix it (or to diagnose remotely if possible)

Comment: I know this is two days later and it's probably taken care of, but... What USD Matt said in his answer.  To be more specific, beeping is usually a hardware issue, in my experience a failed disk in RAID (or a power supply, like ewwhite said).  If it's a hardware issue, not only will it not be fixed by rebooting the system, but there's a chance it won't come back up.  You do *not* want to be the person who rebooted the system and had it die and not come back up.  Hopefully everything is all sorted out now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to not have the experience to be messing with this, I would agree with your higher up and not touch it. And no, do not reboot it yourself without any firm reason for doing so. Beeping usually indicates a hardware issue which is not going to be fixed by restarting the system.

It would be useful to know the server model. A lot of modern servers have fault lights that can identify a failed component (For instance the HP/Dell servers I work with have a small diagram of the components, with a light next to each one, sometimes on a 'pop-out' panel). It doesn't have to be raid or a disk, it could be a PSU, memory module or even just a fan.

Not that you would probably have the ability or details to access it, but most servers also have network IPMI access (or something similar) which allows you to view the physical system status and logs. This will often allow you to see problems with the hardware that might not have made it into Windows event logs.

If a supervisor is in tomorrow I would highly suggest putting up with it and waiting for them.

Edit - Just to add: in this situation I would probably speak to management, as I would expect them to want to contact the person responsible for this server. They may be able to talk you or someone else through diagnosing the issue, or if it's a critical system they may be required to come back in.

Tasking an intern with trying to silence an alarm on a system you know little about, which is quite possibly faulty, is completely the wrong thing to be doing.